# Excel Sum function - Return cells value if a range is blank

Tags: excel-formula

I am using Excel 2019. I am using Sum function to find the sum of a range of cells. But if one cell as value, then this value should be displayed, if two cell in this range as value sum function, any help please

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give an example?  Your title says one thing and your description seems to say another.

Answer (score 0):

The text of the question is not super clear, but in general, you can use `SUMIF`  to avoid errors.

Something like `=SUMIF(range, "<>N/A")` might be what you are looking for, since the `SUM` function will work on a range with a mix of cells that are truly blank.

Answer (score 0):

I have 4 cells with value from a pivot table, I want to make a summary of all 4 cells, but if the pivot change, and 1 cell no longer have value, the remains will summarize, if 3 of them don't have value the remain will just show...

I don't know if I explain it very well... My English is not good enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM9lw.png)